# Specified output array "TFlite_Detection_PostProcess" is not produced by any op in this graph" even though it exist in graph

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I was following the instruction in [this](https://medium.com/tensorflow/training-and-serving-a-realtime-mobile-object-detector-in-30-minutes-with-cloud-tpus-b78971cf1193), for converting my `ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco` model to `tflite`. I already exported my model to tflite which produced tflite_graph.pb and then when Iconvert it to .tflite file with the command line

```
tflite_convert --graph_def_file=tflite_graph.pb \
                --output_file=detect1.tflite \
                --input_shapes=1,300,300,3 \
                --input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor \
                --output_arrays=TFlite_Detection_PostProcess \
                --change_concat_input_ranges=false \
                --allow_custom_ops
```

It says that

> Check failed: GetOpWithOutput(model, output_array) Specified output
>   array "TFlite_Detection_PostProcess" is not produced by any op in this
>   graph.  Is it a typo? To silence this message, pass this flag:
>   allow_nonexistent_arrays.

`TFLite_Detection_PostProcess` really exist in my graph. Here is the image that proves it

[image]

Comment: I am receiving the same error. Were you able to figure your issue?

Comment: instead of using `--output_arrays=TFlite_Detection_PostProcess` i used `--output_arrays=TFLite_Detection_PostProcess,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3` @ruggershawn